# Multi-node connection management

Tags: linux, networking, network-programming, network-protocols, rdma

I'm designing an application involving multi-node communications using Infiniband (ibv_*). What is the standard way to keep connections between nodes? I'm thinking of O(N^2) connections for all pairs of node as the easiest one, but it's kind of silly and not scalable.

Comment: Will you need RDMA operations between the nodes, or do you plan only to use send and receive operations?

Comment: Also, can you tell in advance what will be the communication pattern between the nodes? Perhaps you could dynamically create RC connections and avoid using O(N^2) connections.

Comment: Yes I need RDMA operation.

Answer (score 2):

The question is kinda simple and short, but the real answer is VERY long...

First of all, be sure that you really need to use ibv_... stuff.

Are you using Infiniband or ROCE?

Next, analyze the expected communication pattern of your application.

You're talking about scalability, which probably means that you have a massively parallel application in mind.
Do you really need to invent your own communication layer?
Can't you use existing solutions?
There's a whole CS field that deals with this kind of problems - HPC (High Performance Computing).
Perhaps [MPI](http://www.open-mpi.org/)/[UPC](http://upc.lbl.gov/)/some other library will solve your problem?

If you still need to write your own ibv_... application with lots and lots of machines, then you need to consider:

- do you need RC or UD connections?
- if you have the newest Mellanox HCA (Connect-IB) then there's also an option of DC
- what are the scalability requirements?
- how sensitive is the application to latency/BW?

To summarize:

- if you need to have a massively parallel IB verbs application, and you need RC, you'd better open RC connections on-demand
- if you have to have all the RC connection opened in advance, then there's no other way - O(n^2) connections case in inevitable
- if it fits your needs, consider using UD
- check that existing solutions are not what you need

Comment: Thank you! I need RC but maybe attaching them on-demand is a way to go.